# how to pass field to other function for filter data linq based on field passed in linq to sql

Tags: vb.net, linq, expression

how to pass field to other function for filter data linq based on field passed in linq to sql?

function is

```
Private Function filter(Of T)(ByVal lnq As IQueryable(Of T), ByVal Field As Func(Of T, String)) As IQueryable(Of T)
   Return lnq.Where(Function(x) Field(x).ToLower.Equals("en")).AsQueryable
End Function
```

example

```
dim lnq = from item in tbls
lnq = filter(of tbl)(lnq, Function(x) x.Culture)
```

run code is error :

```
Method 'System.String Invoke(System.Object[])' has no supported translation to SQL.
```